# Does $\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Does $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}}dx$$ converge?
I have tried to substitiute $x$ in nominator as $\tan{x}$ and simlify it using trigonometric formulas, but the integral was still too difficult.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You should show some effort.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** The **potential** problem for the integrand is for $x$ near $0^+$, where we have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
Are you able to take it from here?

Comment: I don't think so. I have considered your simplification before. I have also tried to substitiute $x$ in nominator as $\tan{x}$ and simlify it using trigonometric formulas, but the integral was still too difficult.

Comment: @MarcinW. You have, for $b>0$ sufficiently small,  $$ 0<\int_{\epsilon}^b \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}}dx \sim \int_{\epsilon}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=[2\sqrt{x}]_{\epsilon}^b = 2\sqrt{b}-2\sqrt{\epsilon}$$ which converges to $2\sqrt{b}<+\infty $ as $\epsilon$ tends to $0^+$.

Comment: Hmm, I have noticed that $\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Could we use this corelation? I think second fraction should be bigger than the first one.

Comment: @MarcinW.You have $\displaystyle \sqrt{x}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{\sin{x}}} \longrightarrow 1$ as $x$ tends to $0$, giving the equivalence I've mentioned in my precedent comment.